# PyTorch: Train without dataloader (loop trough dataframe instead)

Tags: python, neural-network, pandas, pytorch

I was wondering if it is bad practice to instead of using built in tools such as dataloader just loop trough each row in a pandas df. Lets say I am doing text classification and my training loop looks like:

```
net.train()

for i in range(0, 5):
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    print('epoch:', i)

    for idx, row in train_df.iterrows(): #is this bad?
        if idx % 1000 == 0:
            print(idx)
        total_loss = 0
        net.zero_grad()
        text_1, text_2 = row['sentence1'], row['sentence2']

        encoded1 = tokenizer.encode_plus(text_1, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
        encoded2 = tokenizer.encode_plus(text_2, return_tensors="pt").to(device)

        cosine_dist = net(
            encoded1['input_ids'], encoded1['token_type_ids'], encoded1['attention_mask'],
            encoded2['input_ids'], encoded2['token_type_ids'], encoded2['attention_mask'],
        )

        gold_label = torch.tensor([row['score'] / 5.0]).to(device)

        raw_loss = loss(cosine_dist, gold_label)
        raw_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        epoch_loss += raw_loss.item()

    print(epoch_loss)
```

Will this just take longer time, since it does a backprop for each training sample? If using batch training, with e.g batch_size=32, will that only backprop once for 32 samples, meaning it should be faster, but optimizing the average loss in the batch?

Any feedback is appreciated! :)

Comment: The training this way might be unstable; think a simpler case of MNIST, each row has 7 for 5k rows at stretch and then suddenly some other number appears, what will happen to your weights?

Comment: What if you just randomly shuffle the data first?

Comment: Well we can do that for sure yet the updates to your weights will be quite frequent and ultimately might lead to instability in it.(keep jumping b/w sweet spots and random noise) Plus you won't be leveraging advantage of GPUs etc, so doesn't seem a good thing to do intuitively